# How to use 2 "urlopen" in the same cell in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, urllib

I would like to have 2 "with urllib.request.urlopen" requests in the same cell in jupyter notebook. The first one gives a nextpagetoken for the second one.

If I separate the two requests in two cells both work.

If both requests are in the same cell, the second request ends in a status: `"INVALID REQUEST"`.

My first idea was, that the first with `urllib.request.urlopen` needs to be closed somehow in order to have more than one request in a cell, but I didn't find a solution which solved the issue.

separate the two requests in two cells --> Works, but I need it in 1 cell

try to `close()` first request --> no change

```
#open first link to build list of place_ids
with urllib.request.urlopen(LINK) as y:
    x_dict = json.loads(y.read().decode())
    next_page_token = x_dict["next_page_token"]
    #potential solution that does not work: y.close()

#open second link with pagetoken
with urllib.request.urlopen(LINK WITH NEXTPAGETOKEN) as y_page2:
    x_dict_page_2=json.loads(y_page2.read().decode())
    print(x_dict_page_2)
```

expected output: second urllib.request.urlopen gives results

actual output: second urllib.request.urlopen gives:

```
{'html_attributions': [], 'results': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

time.sleep()

between the two requests and it will work